# Declare type of function declaration instead of function expression

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript2.0

I am looking to declare the type of a function declaration, like this:

```
function foo(){


}
```

however, I am not sure how to do this. Instead, I have simply been changing the above to a function expression like so:

```
const foo = function(){

};
```

then I can add type info, like so:

```
const foo : ISpecialFunc = function(){

};

foo.x = 'bar';  // etc
```

Is there a way to declare type information for a function which is a declaration and not an expression? Or maybe that doesn't make sense, or is not supposed to make sense?

Comment: Are you instantiating it or is it returning an instance?

Comment: sorry, huh? I am just declaring a function..honestly when declaring a function, all it can be is a function, I guess. That's the way JS works. So maybe it simply doesn't make sense to have a type for it.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
type ISpecialFunc = {
    (): void;
    x: string;
};

const foo = function () {

} as ISpecialFunc;

foo.x = 'bar';
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20ISpecialFunc%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%09()%3A%20void%3B%0D%0A%09x%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20foo%20%3D%20function%20()%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D%20as%20ISpecialFunc%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afoo.x%20%3D%20'bar'%3B))

---

#### Edit

I don't think that you can type a "function declaration" this way.
What you can do is cast:

```
function foo() {

};

interface foo  {
    (): void;
    x: string;
};

(foo as foo).x = 'bar';
```

Comment: ummm, foo is still an expression not a declaration :)

Comment: Check my revised answer

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't make sense to set the type of the function... rather, you want to type the response of the function:

```
function foo(): ResponseTypeHere {

}
```

If you're trying to actually type the function, you should look at typescripts classes where you can implement interfaces

```
class Foo implements IInterfaceName {

}

const bar = new Foo();
```

Comment: well, in theory a function expression might lead to "a different type of a function", but a function declaration in JS will always to be just a plain vanilla function, AFAICT. Functions can inherit and also have properties, and that's why as you can see in my original question it's possible to "type" a function expression. No downvote, but no upvote either here.